# How do I create an npm package that I can import into sveltekit?

Tags: svelte-3, sveltekit

I would like to create a simple npm package and import that into svelte components, however, I cannot seem to use index files to import deeply nested files, e.g.

```
// routes/test.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { Test } from '@my-co/my-lib/dist/folder1/folder2/test';
  const test = new Test('foo', 'bar');
</script>
```

works, but

```
// routes/test.svelte
<script lang="ts">
  import { Test } from '@my-co/my-lib';
  const test = new Test('foo', 'bar');
</script>
```

does not. I have the following in the index.ts file in my npm module:

```
export { Test } from './folder1/folder2/test';
```

This strangely also does seem to work in ssr (dev server output in console seems to pick the `import {Test} from '@my-co/my-lib'` correctly), but not in the browser, where I get the error that Test is not a constructor...

**Npm library package.json:**

```
{
  "name": "@myco/my-lib",
  "version": "0.0.2",
  "main": "dist/index.js",
  "types": "dist/index.d.ts",
  "files": [
    "dist"
  ],
  "scripts": {
    "build": "tsc",
    "prepare": "npm run build"
  },
  "author": "redacted",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "@types/rosie": "0.0.40",
    "@types/slug": "^5.0.3",
    "rosie": "^2.1.0",
    "slug": "^5.1.1"
  }
}
```

**Npm library tsconfig**

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "declaration": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "module": "es2015",
    "target": "es5",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "lib": ["es2015", "dom"],
    "rootDir": "src"
  },
  "include": ["src"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "dist"]
}
```

**Lib structure**

```
my-lib/
| dist/
| node_modules/
| src/
| | folder1/
| | | folder2/
| | | | test.ts
```

**test.ts**

```
export class Test {
  foo: string;
  bar: string;

  constructor(foo: string, bar: string) {
    this.foo = foo;
    this.bar = bar;
  }

  testMe() {
    console.log("foobar", this.foo, this.bar);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While Caleb's answer did not really help in my case, I think it was a bit of a pointer as to what was going wrong. I did not intend to write a svelte-focused Component library, but rather a general model/factory library to be reused between the front- and backend.

I did a couple of things since this issue occurred and here is a list of things I think went wrong:

- Local linking of the npm package into my project caused issues (`npm link`). I have very little experience with all the build tools in sveltekit but figured out where those stale/non-functional libs are referenced from. I deleted the `node-modules/.vite` folder which sometimes resolved my issues (I `grep`ed for seemingly cached values which led me to this directory. In my dev experience quite uncommon to have found build artifacts in `node-modules`, so that was a bit tedious to find in that place).
- I converted my npm package to a hybrid ESM/CJS module (previously CommonJS only). I'm unsure whether that resolved the initial issues, but might be worth a try.

I think the main issue was the local linking and some sort of build caching going on in vite.

That being said, I haven't encountered any issues with the library ever since.

Answer (score 3):

The `svelte-kit package` command should automatically do everything for you ([docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/packaging)).

[This Youtube video](https://youtu.be/_TymiadmPrc) should explain everything.

The steps it provides to publish are:

1. `npm init svelte@next project-name`
2. `cd project-name`
3. Create component
4. `npx svelte-kit package`
5. `cd package`
6. Login to npm / create an account
7. `npm publish --access public`

Comment: I wonder how to make this `svelte-kit package` available to an existing project.